# Rename all files in a folder in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, unix

I have a folder that contains files with names like `statData, Results, FinalData` and I would like to make a simple change on their names so that each name starts with a number such as `1_statData, 1_Results, 1_FinalData`

For this I used the following command:

```
$ for FILENAME in *; do mv $FILENAME 2_$FILENAME; done
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Did you type the initial `$` as part of your command, or is that your shell prompt?

Comment: @melpomene Genius, I would never have thought of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example and it works when I removed the `$` at the beginning of your command

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the answer of @Nasser, I would add that your example will not work if your filenames contain spaces. You should use

```
for FILENAME in *; do mv "$FILENAME" "2_$FILENAME"; done
```

instead...